# Updating caches in a sequential, unthreaded C/C++/Fortran program

Tags: performance, caching, architecture

So we all know that modern microprocessors all have a hierarchy of caches in addition to the DRAM memory to make the accessing of frequently used data faster.

I want to know how the cache is kept in sync with the DRAM memory.

To be more precise, let us say I have a variable of  `double a` which is being updated 
by a single unthreaded process, say `a+=1.0`

Say I have two data caches `L1` and `L2`.

1. Does the processor first update the copy of `a` in L1, then the copy in L2, and then finally 
   the copy in DRAM  memory?
2. Or does the processor first update the value of `a` in DRAM memory and then bring in the appropriately sized cache-lines ***containing*** `a` into L2 and then L1?

Sure this process is invisible to the programmer, and is carried out by the operating system and or processor but I was interested in knowing the details of how this works.

I mentioned C/C++/Fortran languages, since these are the 'lowest-level' languages I am most familiar with, and I am interested in knowing whether I can control caching behavior in such languages.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#Writing_policies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different processors take different approaches. There is not a single, unique straight answer to your question.

**UPDATE** (see the comment below)

First of all, consider the difference between inclusive and exclusive caches.

In the case of an inclusive cache, if `a` is in L1 cache, then it is also in L2 and in L3, since this is a memory hierarchy. It is impossible for `a` to be in a level-N cache and not be in a level-N+1 cache. However, note that the opposite can happen, and often does (e.g. being in L3 but not on L2).

In a truly exclusive cache, what is in L1 will never be in L2 or L3.

What happens with your example depends on the write policy in use. There are two different options here, known as *write-through*, or *write-back*. Apart from that, one also has to consider the write allocate policy, which dictates whether a write instruction to an uncached object will have to fetch that object into cache in the first place. The write allocate policy can be *write-allocate*, meaning a missing object is brought to cache before being written, or it can be *no-write-allocate*, which means that the object is not brought to cache and is directly written in the backing store.

About the write-policy:

*Write-through* means that as long as the object is written, its value in memory (and across every cache level) is immediately updated.

*Write-back* means that the object's value is updated in cache only; it is only updated in memory when it is necessary to take it out of the cache.

Note that **write-through** can be used with any write allocate policy; on the other hand, it doesn't make much sense to talk about **write-back** with a no-write-allocate policy.

As for your specific questions:

> Does the processor first update the copy of a in L1, then the copy in
>   L2, and then finally the copy in DRAM memory?

If it's using a write-allocate policy together with write-through, yes, that's exactly what happens. If it's using write-allocate with write-back, then `a += 1.0` will bring the object to L3, L2 and L1 cache in the first time, and subsequent instructions will only update the copy in L1, assuming no replacement is necessary. If it's using no-write-allocate, the memory is written without bringing in the block to cache.

However, note that `a += 1.0` goes down to "Read a; Add 1; Update a", the "Read A" step will most likely bring `a` to cache, which means that this isn't really a write operation, but rather a read-and-then-write operation. Thus, even if no-write-allocate is used, I would say `a` is always brought to cache, so what really happens only depends on the write policy (write-through or write-back). Write-allocate is only relevant when we have straight `write` instructions into objects that are not cached, like `a = 1.0;`.

> Or does the processor first update the value of a in DRAM memory and
>   then bring in the appropriately sized cache-lines containing a into L2
>   and then L1?

That never happens. If no-write-allocate is used, the memory is directly manipulated. Otherwise, the object is always brought to L3, L2, and L1 cache (and this is "automagically" handled by the cache controller, the CPU itself doesn't have to worry about bringing it to each cache separately), and then what happens depends on the write policy.

All of this assumes that no replacement of the object in cache is necessary throughout your program's execution, which is unrealistic. A popular replacement policy is LRU (Least Recently Used). Cache conflicts are the major source of needed replacement, and when they occur depends on the cache's organization: its size, its block size, and, most importantly, its associativity. Wikipedia has in-depth information about this; for a more serious opinion on this matter, and if you want to learn more about caches, I recommend Chapter 5 from Computer Organization and Design - The Hardware/Software Interface, by Patterson & Henessy.

Comment: Inclusiveness is per cache level, it's possible that the L3 will be inclusive and the L2 won't (modern Intel CPUs for e.g. have this). The biggest benefit on an inclusive cache (IMHO) is that it serves as a snoop filter, and you don't really need more than one level of filtering.